# Can we get Community a hat too?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-user, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

Last year, [Community ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) had a wonderful Santa Claus's hat on.

[image]

However, this year I can't see Community wearing a hat. Could we please bring that back? Although it is not so important, it greatly enhances the festive mood.

Comment: I had no idea that that was even a thing. I'll look into it, but it will have to wait until next week, and then only if it'll be relatively easy to do.

Comment: @YaakovEllis - It's something any moderator can do from Community's profile. Takes about five seconds?

Comment: @Mithical only if it already qualified for a hat. I don't think it does yet - otherwise you would see the blue hat on the badges widget on its profile.

Comment: Yeah, there's no hats earned by Community yet, so there's not much we can do. I am glad you liked the hat from last year, I think I was the one who put it on. :P

Comment: I can cheat for community on Sunday. In the meantime, can y'all tell me what hat you want to see?

Comment: @Catija Was Community's hat last year just an edit to the profile pic, or was it an actual hat?

Comment: @CodyGray Actual hat. You can tell because it's outside the frame... it's hard to see because the frame isn't visible in the image above but the logo didn't change size. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per your requests, [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile) is now sporting some new hat-wear:

> [image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: That’s great!!!

Comment: I should blame caching I guess...

Answer (score 13):

> In the meantime, can y'all tell me what hat you want to see?

How about Silencium?

[image]

Comment: This was the one I was going to recommend.

Comment: I kinda think that looks perfect for them

Answer (score 5):

[image: 007 Community]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Community with a hat]